# Newsletter looks bad in Outlook, elements not aligned

Tags: html, email, outlook, mailchimp, newsletter

I'm designing a newsletter for a client, and I'm having trouble getting some elements to display correctly in Outlook. It looks fine in the MailChimp preview and in my own inbox in both Windows 10 Mail and Outlook.com, but when my client opens it in Outlook, it doesn't.

The main issue is a group of divs each containing an image and a bit of text. They should be lined up in two rows of four, but in Outlook they are all displayed underneath each other.

Here's the code that I put into MailChimps codeblock in the newsletter:

```
<style type="text/css">@media screen and (max-width:480px)
{
div{font-size:12px}
a.single{line-height:2.25em;display:block}
a.double{line-height:1.5em;display:block}
}
</style>
<div style="display:table-row;">
<div style="float:left; display: block; text-align:center; vertical-align: top; width: 25%;"><a class="single" href="https://letlej.dk/store/?shop=category&amp;showcat=23"><img data-file-id="410427" height="100" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/32e5243136b10b277aba1e9d2/images/9f1c92ca-7906-4383-8317-5524960adfd3.png" style="border: 0px  ; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px;" width="100" /><br />
Hoppeborge</a></div>

<div style="float:left; display: block; text-align:center; vertical-align: top; width: 25%;"><a class="single" href="https://letlej.dk/store/?shop=category&amp;showcat=28"><img data-file-id="410419" height="100" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/32e5243136b10b277aba1e9d2/images/7ba4f938-8428-4320-be5b-10f4f0816eae.png" style="border: 0px  ; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px;" width="100" /><br />
RodeoTyre</a></div>

<div style="float:left; display: block; text-align:center; vertical-align: top; width: 25%;"><a class="double" style="display:block;"><img data-file-id="410407" height="100" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/32e5243136b10b277aba1e9d2/images/7435cd65-9d37-4ed0-b43c-859647d72ae2.png" style="border: 0px  ; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px;" width="100" /><br />
Sport og Action</a></div>

<div style="float:left; display: block; text-align:center; vertical-align: top; width: 25%;"><a class="single" href="https://letlej.dk/store/?shop=category&amp;showcat=33"><img data-file-id="410411" height="100" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/32e5243136b10b277aba1e9d2/images/760861f6-f4ff-4208-951d-a77c08b16393.png" style="border: 0px initial ; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px;" width="100" /><br />
Kraftpr&oslash;ver</a></div>
</div>

<div style="display:table-row;">
<div style="float:left; display: block; text-align:center; vertical-align: top; width: 25%;"><a class="double" href="https://letlej.dk/store/?shop=category&amp;showcat=44"><img data-file-id="410415" height="100" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/32e5243136b10b277aba1e9d2/images/7159316b-b896-41cd-b948-fcb4978c8aff.png" style="border: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px;" width="100" /><br />
Store aktiviteter</a></div>

<div style="float:left; display: block; text-align:center; vertical-align: top; width: 25%;"><a class="single" href="https://letlej.dk/store/?shop=category&amp;showcat=51"><img data-file-id="410435" height="100" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/32e5243136b10b277aba1e9d2/images/9d64f34c-d304-4476-b733-bd7f0202b8c4.png" style="border: 0px  ; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px;" width="100" /><br />
Jukebokse</a></div>

<div style="float:left; display: block; text-align:center; vertical-align: top; width: 25%;"><a class="single" href="https://letlej.dk/store/?shop=category&amp;showcat=53"><img data-file-id="410423" height="100" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/32e5243136b10b277aba1e9d2/images/2af88d8a-1c0b-421c-aa16-9d98bf5418c5.png" style="border: 0px  ; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px;" width="100" /><br />
Madvogne</a></div>

<div style="float:left; display: block; text-align:center; vertical-align: top; width: 25%;"><a class="single" href="https://letlej.dk/store/?shop=category&amp;showcat=69"><img data-file-id="410431" height="100" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/32e5243136b10b277aba1e9d2/images/eaff7670-1d95-4d87-b504-59e8e26cc82b.png" style="border: 0px  ; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px;" width="100" /><br />
Funfood</a></div>
</div>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: you can use MJML.

Comment: Can you show us all the code, including the wrapper?
It is otherwise difficult to fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

Float is the issue, see https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/positioning-display/float/

Use `display: table-cell`, or better (for full coverage), use native table elements, `tr` and `td` and not `display: table-row` etc.